# How to access getComponent in a derived class in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin6

This is my code. I want to do the following. but im getting exception at getComponent(0) in LoginStep1 class. How should i resolve this.
Im new in vaadin. if my approach is wrong your guidance required.

```java
public class Login extends VerticalLayout implements View {
    public static String viewName = "login";

    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        removeAllComponents();
        CustomLayout viewScreen = new CustomLayout("screens/screen-login");

        Component step1 = new LoginStep1().getLoginStep1();

        viewScreen.addComponent(step1, "login-steps");
        addComponent(viewScreen);
    }
}
```

```java
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginStep1 extends Login {
    public Component getLoginStep1() {
        CustomLayout stepScreen = new CustomLayout("components/screens/login-step1");
        Button loginBtn = CommonComponents.getButton("Login", "btn btn-green btn-block");

        loginBtn.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                // this line gives me exception.
                CustomLayout currentLayout = (CustomLayout) getComponent(0);
                currentLayout.addComponent(new LoginStep2().getLoginStep2(request, posInfoResponse.getBody()), "login-steps");
            }
        });
    }

    stepScreen.addComponent(loginBtn,"login-btn");
    return stepScreen;
}
```

**it gives following exception**

```
com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager$RpcInvocationException: Unable to invoke method click in com.vaadin.shared.ui.button.ButtonServerRpc
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:160)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:408)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:79)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1409)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:158)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method buttonClick in com.herman.login.LoginStep1$1 failed.
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:528)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1003)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:377)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:54)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractOrderedLayout.getComponent(AbstractOrderedLayout.java:414)
    at com.herman.login.LoginStep1$1.buttonClick(LoginStep1.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: Morfic any solution.

Comment: Is `getLoginStep1()` executed before entering the `Login` view? By the looks of it, you're executing that method before actually adding any components...

Comment: but morfic if i add getLoginStep1() method in same class Login it works fine

Comment: Because they're in the same instance of the object as opposed to the semi-cyclic calls you have now. I assume you're navigating to `Login` when you're getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Some things are still unclear since you haven't answered all the comments, so
I'm unsure which of the 3 implementations (`Login`, `LoginStep1` or `LoginStep2`) you're using as a view for navigation with the navigator component. However, looking at `Login` & `LoginStep1`, I can see a something that you may want to reconsider in the current design: you're creating a new instances of your inherited classes and invoking methods on them, instead of using the current instances...

Since the sources for `LoginStep2` are not available, I'll try to cover the other 2 scenarios:

**1)** Suppose you're navigating to an instance of `Login`.

- When the `enter` method is called, a new instance of `LoginStep1` is created and added to the component list inside a `CustomLayout`.
- When you click the *login* button, the `getComponent(0)` is invoked on the new instance of `LoginStep1` which does not inherit from the `Login` instance used in navigation, hence it contains 0 components leading to your exception

**2)** Suppose you're navigating to an instance of `LoginStep1`, which extends `Login`.

- When the enter event is triggered and the `enter` method inherited from the superclass is executed, a new instance of `LoginStep1` is created and added to the component list inside a `CustomLayout`.
- When you click the *login* button, the `getComponent(0)` is invoked on the new instance of `LoginStep1` which has nothing to do with the current `LoginView1` instance used in navigation, hence it contains 0 components leading to your exception

---

In conclusion, this is more likely related to basic java inheritance concepts than to Vaadin, and the main question may be `Component step1 = new LoginStep1().getLoginStep1(); // <= why create a new instance?`

```java
public class Login extends VerticalLayout implements View {
    public static String viewName = "login";

    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        removeAllComponents();
        CustomLayout viewScreen = new CustomLayout("screens/screen-login");

        Component step1 = new LoginStep1().getLoginStep1(); // <= why create a new instance?

        viewScreen.addComponent(step1, "login-steps");
        addComponent(viewScreen);
    }
}
```